# Start & kill fcitx by shortcut

Tags: kde, input-language, fcitx

I'm using caps lock to switch between languages, but fcitx seems to be not support this. So, is it possible to load/unload fcitx with japanese mozc input only by some shortcut, but for other two languages use KDE keyboard settings? Or this behaviour (language switching with caps lock) is possible inside fcitx itself?

Comment: It's not totally clear what you want to do. What the the other languages you want, and are they IME languages or keyboard layouts?

Comment: I have a shell function which does that for me with sogou/fcitx input, but i am away from my laptop. Remind me about this question please in 24 hours

Comment: I need russian, english and japanese (with mozc) languages and switch between it with caps lock. If this is not possible, at least will be great to turn on/off fcitx with turned on mozc by some shortcut. I may write script, which will check, is it running, and execute "fcitx" or "killall fcitx" commands, but this looks like a dirty hack, and not restores previous keyboard layout

Comment: Why not just use `ibus-mozc` instead of `fcitx-mozc`?

Comment: Previously I used Anthy with ibus, but now, for some reason, can not setup it. Will try mozc inside ibus, maybe this will be better

Answer (score 0):

Open 'Text Entry' in System Setting.

[image: Text Entry window]

Then, click on the red marked button and the window named 'Input Method Configuration' comes up.

Click on Global Config and you can set keys or shortcuts to enable or disable Mozc by changing blue-marked buttons.

[image: 3 languages]

As per request of comment, if you want to circle among 3 languages, add one more at the Text Entry and set a shortcut to switch among the languages. For example, I set Both Shift keys and every time I press Left and Right shift keys at the same time, English - Russian - Japanese take turns.

Comment: Don't works:  caps lock works with it's native behavior and as switch key same time. If bind caps lock to "super" in KDE keyboard settings, this works, but can switch between 2 languages only: for switch to 3rd language have to change indicator by mouse

Comment: One of the sample, when you want to use 3 languages, edited original answer.

Comment: Maybe this will works in Gnome, but not with KDE:( When I enable switch by caps lock in KDE keyboard settings, fcitx configuration tool can not see it as activation key. When switch key is disabled in KDE layer, fcitx just enable caps lock standard mode instead on switching. For now will be activate mozc by mouse pressing on fcitx icon with only two layouts - it will be enough for now. There are another bug in KDE generic japanese layout: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=414560

Comment: So you can avoid a caps-lock key until the bug will be fixed. I like double shift and the key next to the space bar which often R_Alt or R_Ctrl. It's handy as a Caps-lock key close enough to the home position, pressed by right hand little finger or palm of it. Ctrl+Space is also useful when your control key is located in between Shift and Tab.